# Ios smartface in action app crashes at ios9

Tags: smartface.io

i want to use ios emulator but smartface app crashes after ios9 update. How to use emulator for Ios9 operating system? Or need to wait app market update for new operating system?

Comment: Which setup of Smartface are you using? There is iOS 9 support in the latest release (4.4.0.3).

Comment: the app called "smartface in action" which is emulator app of smartface downloaded from ios appstore is not running on ios9. Does it work in your device?

Comment: Alex, do you have a licence? Which version of Smartface are you using right now? With Smartface 440, iOS emulator is only available for licenced users. What is the error you are getting?